# Strange bytes added to end of JPG files on SD card

Tags: backup, sd-card, photos, jpeg

A month ago, my wife upgraded from a Galaxy S5 to S7, and brought along a MicroSD card full of photos taken on the old phone.  Recently, in the process of backing up new photos, I noticed that a lot of old photos have been given "new" file modification dates, which I find alarming.  Large batches of photos have updated modtimes while the phone is connected to WiFi not doing anything.

I grabbed a sample modified JPG and compared it to the backed-up original.  The file is identical up to the length of the original, but has some new bytes tacked onto the end of the file:

[image: Bytes appended to end of JPG image on phone]

What is this?  I see "BackupRestore_Data", which looks like a signature from some kind of online backup system, but I'm not aware of us opting into such a system.  I also see "SEFT" which could be a magic number at the end, but searching for that didn't produce anything that looked relevant.

It doesn't seem to hurt the JPG to have this extra data appended.  But generally I'm not a fan of the files being changed at all after the photo was taken. What is this extra data and what does it do?

Comment: This question is specifically not on topic here at Superuser.  I can't vote to migrate because your asking for the impossible, for us to identify what software modified the photo, we have no idea what software you have installed on the phone.

Comment: darn i have the exact same problem, it's screwing dropbox camera backups getting the files constantly reuploaded with this garbage

Comment: I found this junk added to the end of .mp4 files as well! The first number after `BackupRestore_Data` and until the underscore was my SIM's IMEI number as well. I have absolutely not installed any kind of backup software.

Comment: Just discovered this too. It has caused chaos for me as I use the Google Photos app, which detected the changed files and re-uploaded them, creating duplicates in my library.

Answer (score 2):

The data seems to be some kind of hash, that whatever backup software is happening is using it to track which files have already been uploaded, and which ones haven't.  Also hashes, if the hash is for the whole file it can be used to determine if the file has been altered since its last upload.

Many picture formats support metadata which is added to the pictures for the users benefit.  This includes, but is not limited to EXIF and XMP profiles which allow all kind of information to be embedded that would otherwise be lost.

The most important camera information is embedded.  Tags containing the names of people in the pictures can be added afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my S7. Don't know what program is adding this meta data but the numbers following BackupRestore_Data is the device IMEI number.

Using Exif tool I gathered that it seems the data is an exif maker note from a Samsung app.

```
D:\>exiftool -s -G -U "2016-08-26 14.15.38-1.jpg"
[MakerNotes] Unknown_0x0001 : 0100
[MakerNotes] Unknown_0x0002 : 73728
[MakerNotes] Unknown_0x000c : 0
[MakerNotes] Unknown_0x0010 : undef
[MakerNotes] Unknown_0x0040 : 0
[MakerNotes] Unknown_0x0050 : 1
[MakerNotes] Unknown_0x0100 : 0
[MakerNotes] TimeStamp : 2016:08:26 14:15:38+02:00
[MakerNotes] SamsungTrailer_0x0a41Name : BackupRestore_Data
[MakerNotes] SamsungTrailer_0x0a41 : (Binary data 20 bytes, use -b option to extract)

D:\>exiftool.exe -SamsungTrailer_0x0a41Name -b -u "2016-08-26 14.15.38-1.jpg"
Warning: [minor] Unknown APP4 segment - 2016-08-26 14.15.38-1.jpg
BackupRestore_Data

D:\>exiftool.exe -SamsungTrailer_0x0a41 -b -u "2016-08-26 14.15.38-1.jpg"
Warning: [minor] Unknown APP4 segment - 2016-08-26 14.15.38-1.jpg
3588100754?????_1458 (I have masked that last 5 numbers in the IMEI)
```

Comment: @fixer1234 I agree after rereading the now formatted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This data is added to JPG and MP4 files (at least) without the user's consent, by some piece of software on Samsung Galaxy smartphones. The part between `BackupRestore_Data` and the next underscore is the phone's IMEI number, posing a potentially serious privacy concern.

There is very little known at the moment - see a [thread on XDA-Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s7/help/photos-modified-days-t3451600) where a user's photos of guns were marked with this signature.

I've had completely innocuous pictures of landscape marked.

The signature seems to be coming in two shapes:

- 79 bytes, containing an ending byte sequence, "SEFT"
- 59 bytes, when "SEFHe [...35 bytes here...] SEFT" already existed in the file

Answer (score 0):

I am presently discussing this issue with Samsung support. In the meantime, I looked at list of applications installed on my device (on my S6 running Android 6.0.1 this is accessed via Settings > Application Manager > MORE > Show system apps). I see two interesting entries, both of which are system apps:

- Backup and restore
- Backup and Restore Agent

I don't use any built-in backup software. Imagine my surprise when I looked at the battery usage for Backup and Restore Agent and found it has used 2% of my battery, which seems like a fairly significant level of usage. What is this program doing?

Comment: Thanks for getting in touch with Samsung on this!  When you get their answer, please edit this post to remove the added questions and include their answer.  Your new questions here should be posted separately from this, as their own questions, per the normal organization of Stack Exchange sites.